# Why stateChangeStart event called twice?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use `$stateChangeStart` for check user when change state.
This is my code

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
    if (!toState.data.require_authentication) {
        return;
    }

    // Because state change is called two times, to prevent infinite loop I remove is_authenticate for next re-check and return
    if (toState.data.is_authenticate) {
        toState.data.is_authenticate = false;
        return;
    }

    event.preventDefault();

    toState.data.is_authenticate = false;

    // Check validity of token
    authService.checkAuthToken(function(result, status) {
        if (result.fn.result.done) {
            toState.data.is_authenticate = true;
            //$state.go(toState, toParams, options);
            $state.go(toState, toParams);
        } else {
            $log.debug("AuthToken expire/wrong");
            storageService.reset();
            $state.go("page.login");
        }
        return;
    });

});
```

With some console log I see that when $state.go is fired, for some reason `$stateChangeStart` is fired again, so I need to return out by a boolean params or I enter in an infinite loop...
Why?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to check some articles on UI Router and Authentication, however you can substitute `$state.go()` with [`$state.transitionTo()`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_transitionto) and setting `notify` option to false to avoid broadcast of `$stateChangeStart` event.

Interesting articles:

- http://lean.mean.software/2015/01/05/authentication-with-the-angularjs-ui-router/
- http://solidfoundationwebdev.com/blog/posts/require-authentication-for-certain-routes-with-ui-router-in-angularjs

Comment: But it would be nice if I can pass options state by state, and default options use `notify: true`, if you set to false not work